# get index by value in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, enums, typescript

Reading the 'enum' in typescript, I see this code compiled to javascript.

```
var Season = [];
Season[Season["Spring"] = 0] = "Spring";
Season[Season["Summer"] = 1] = "Summer";
Season[Season["Fall"] = 2] = "Fall";
Season[Season["Winter"] = 3] = "Winter";

console.log(Season.Spring); // 0
console.log(Season[0]); // Spring
```

and,  if I change Season to {} empty objext at first line, this also works and it makes sense.
I don't know what's happening hear.
What is this?

Edit: Yes. This is not what compiler generate. Compiler uses empty object. But if I changed it to empty array. It still works. My question was why array also works good. At first my question included both version, but someone edited question and delete object-use version.

Comment: That is what happens when a compiler writes JavaScript.

Comment: Actually this isn't what the compiler generates. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35075698/390330

Comment: Arrays are Objects, so if all you are doing is assigning properties using square bracket notation, then the two behave exactly the same. Arrays have a special length property, but aren't special otherwise (their inherited properties are mostly generic and can be applied to any suitable object).

Comment: @RobG Thanks, this is what i did wonder.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
Season[Season["Spring"] = 0] = "Spring";
Season[Season["Summer"] = 1] = "Summer";
Season[Season["Fall"] = 2] = "Fall";
Season[Season["Winter"] = 3] = "Winter";`
```

Creates eight properties in Season object:

```
Season["Spring"] = 0;
Season["Summer"] = 1;
Season["Fall"] = 2;
Season["Winter"] = 3;
Season[0] = "Spring";
Season[1] = "Summer";
Season[2] = "Fall";
Season[3] = "Winter";
```

After that Season can be requested:

1. by text to get its index (first four properties)
2. by index to get its text (second four properties)

Comment: but, 
console.log(Seson.length)  // 4
Doesn't it mean Season is array? So, how can array have "Spring" property like object?

Comment: @monad98 the question you are asking is wrong. That is not the JavaScript that the compiler generates : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35075698/390330

Comment: @monad98  Array is an object too, with some specifics: `Array.prototype.length` is a last occupied integer index + 1.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like someone is just trying to make Season be a bidirectional map.

In other words, you can look up items by numeric index or by their string value.

```
var season1     = Season[1];        // season1 == 'Summer'
var summerIndex = Season['Summer']; // summerIndex == 1
```

Comment: Yes. But this is not what the op is questioning http://stackoverflow.com/a/35075698/390330

Answer (score 1):

I'll address your question as to why it still works if you change the first statement in your code block to `var Season = [];` so that `Season` is an array instead of an empty object. Arrays are also objects, and you can set any property you like on an object in JavaScript, even arrays (as long as you don't run the object through `Object.freeze`). So the expression `Season["Spring"] = 0` is simply setting a property named "Spring" on the `Season` object which you could access using `Season["Spring"]` or `Season.Spring` the same as you would on any other object.

Answer (score 0):

> if I change Season to {} empty objext at first line, this also works and it makes sense

I have some [docs about enums](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html), but your question is why:

```
Season = [];
```

Instead of

```
Season = {};
```

When in actuality the following TypeScript:

```
enum Season {
    Spring,
    Summer,
    Fall,
    Winter
}
```

Generates [the JavaScript](http://goo.gl/NLoJFR):

```
var Season;
(function (Season) {
    Season[Season["Spring"] = 0] = "Spring";
    Season[Season["Summer"] = 1] = "Summer";
    Season[Season["Fall"] = 2] = "Fall";
    Season[Season["Winter"] = 3] = "Winter";
})(Season || (Season = {}));
```

And as you can see `Season = {}`. So it should make sense to you.

## PS:

Not your question but, if you are curious about `Season[Season["Spring"] = 0] = "Spring";` [that is covered here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html).

Comment: Thank you~! It helped me a lot for understanding enums